# Partially decompressible compression format

Tags: compression, 7zip

I have a large number of files. Each file is relatively small, and there's a lot of repetition between files, but very much less within each file.

I would like a compression format that would allow me to decompress each file individually, without having to decompress the entire archive. Whilst archive formats like 7z, zip, RAR, do allow this, they do so by compressing only a single file/group of files at once, and then decompressing that file/group of files on demand. In effect you don't actually get the full benefits of compression, especially when the repetition is mostly between, not in, files.

Does anyone know of a compression format that supports this?

Answer (score 2):

The .tar.gz format does take advantage of correlations between files, and you can build an index to the .gz file that would allow you to access the data randomly. ([See](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/develop/examples/zran.h) [zran](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/develop/examples/zran.c).) However if you don't want the index to be as large as all of the uncompressed data (in which case you would not need the compressed file at all), then the random access entry points would occur only occasionally, say every few megabytes of the uncompressed data. You would then need to decompress, on the average half of that number of bytes of uncompressed data before you get to the particular desired small file.

Any compressor that depends on the data from your previous small files to compress them will necessarily need that same data in order to decompress them. There's no getting around that.